# Parsing line in a text file into vectors

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

vector <string> tokenizeString(string filename, string delimiter);

int main() {

    vector<string> tokens = tokenizeString("cityLocation.txt", "-");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
        cout << tokens[i];
    }

    return 0;
}

vector <string> tokenizeString (string filename, string delimiter) {

    size_t pos = 0;
    vector<string>tokens;
    string token;
    ifstream cityText(filename);
    string line;
    while (getline(cityText, line)) {

        while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
            token = line.substr(0,pos);
            tokens.push_back (token);       
            line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
    }


    return (tokens);    
}
```

So this is my code, and my text file data are

> ```
> [1,1]-3-Big_City
> [1,2]-3-Big_City
> [1,3]-3-Big_City
> [2,1]-3-Big_City
> [2,2]-3-Big_City
> [2,3]-3-Big_City
> [2,7]-2-Mid_City
> [2,8]-2-Mid_City
> [3,1]-3-Big_City
> ```

My code is skipping all the Big_city and Mid_city.
It prints out only the first and second column data.

My delimiter is suppose to be '-'.

I haven't tried saving the data into vectors but would like some recommendation on how to do that

Comment: Probably not related but better use `while (std::getline(cityText,line)) {` to read a whole line from the input.

Comment: You only add something to the vector if you find a delimiter. How many delimiters are there in "Big_city" and "Mid_city"?

Comment: Sorry , forgot to add that my delimiter is ' - '

Comment: What he told you was that there is no delimiter after the city part, so it is not extracted by your algorithm. `[3,1]-3-Big_City-` would work with it.

Comment: is there any way to skip the blank spaces after each line?

Comment: in other words: you actually have 2 delimiters: `-` and newline

Comment: Ahhh yes, that actually makes more sense hhaha

Comment: _is there any way to skip the blank spaces after each line?_ You get this for free if you follow the hint of @πάνταῥεῖ in the very first comment.

Comment: @user3413646 You may use `std::istringstream` and another `std::getline()` call with a delimiter specified as `'-'`.

Comment: yes i actually changed it but it didnt print the "Big_city" still

Comment: @Scheff Isn't that specifically *including* the blank spaces at the end of the line (other than newline)? While the `file >> string` will skip any whitespace and works as long as there are no spaces in city names. If spaces are allowed, you need "trim" function, which isn't provided by C++ standard library, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I got it!

Comment: @hyde it is provided, its just not called `trim` but its a combination of `find_last_not_of` and `substr`

Comment: @hyde Yepp. May be, I got it wrong. I was under impression that the blanks at line end should simply be consumed (to not stay in input buffer).

Comment: @user463035818 That's not same as "is provided". It can be done with a multitude of different oneliners, of course, but this is error-prone on multiple levels, may require creating extra unit tests, and so on. It's a trade-off on complexity of standard library of course, but most library creators have deemed trimming to be such a common and important operation (and I agree with that), that a tested function is provided.

Comment: @hyde of course you are right. Sometimes I need someone to tell me that I am wrong ;). I have to admit, I didnt consider the need for additional unit tests, which is crucial for "is provided" or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you need another run for the last field **after** the last delimiter. You can accomplish this by using a post-test loop that will excecute one more time when pos==string::npos, therefore adding `line.substr(pos,string::npos);` as a token which is defined to be the substring from position pos to the end of the string.

```cpp
vector <string> tokenizeString (string filename, string delimiter) {
    vector<string>tokens;
    string token;
    ifstream cityText(filename);
    string line;
    while (cityText >> line) {
        size_t pos = 0, lastpos=0;
        do {
            pos = line.find(delimiter, lastpos);
            token = line.substr(lastpos,pos-lastpos);
            tokens.push_back (token);
            lastpos=pos+1;
        } while (pos != string::npos);
    }
    return (tokens);
}
```